# asmack not getting multi user chat request

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am using asmack library, and facing problem with multiuser chat request.

When sending a conference request, it is not going inside invitation listener, although same code is working with smack library in java.

While debugging it shows that I am receiving the message, but not providing me inside listener.

If anyone of you can help me in this, or at-least tell how to parse the received message which I am getting inside packet listener.

Following is the message :

```
<message from="user1_a1c@conference.server" to="user2@server">
<x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user">
    <invite from="user1@server">
        <reason>Please join me in a conference</reason>
    </invite>
</x>
<x xmlns="jabber:x:conference" jid="user1_a1c@conference.server"/>
```

Comment: Please help me how you add listener for invitation received for the MUC. please help me to do..

Comment: The asmack library of android does not works properly, however the java one works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks !!How you managed to get joined rooms of particular user using asmack API..

Comment: I don't remember it now, may be this link will help : http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the according Providers aren't initialized.

aSmack's [Readme](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/blob/master/README.markdown) did tell you to init the static code of smack, which will initialize the Providers. Did you run the code before doing any XMPP related actions?

Comment: I am using asmack-jse-buddyclound-* , and there no such classes exist.